# tangent plane parallel to a line

Tags: real-analysis

Consider $f(x,y)=xy-y^2+x$. For which $(x,y) \in R^2 $the tangent plane at the graph of f in the point (x,y,f(x,y)) is parallel to the line $\{(x,y,z) : x=0,y=z\}$

I calculate $${\partial_x f(x,y)=y+1}$$ and $${\partial_y f(x,y)=x-2y}$$.

But how can I use this to calculate the plane?

Answer (score 0):

Call the point of tangency $\vec p = (x_0, y_0, z_0)$. Then the curves $\vec v(x) = (x, y_0, f(x, y_0))$ and $\vec w(y) = (x_0, y, f(x_0, y))$ lie within the surface and pass through $\vec p$.

Now $$\vec v'(x_0) = (1, 0, \partial_xf(x_0, y_0))$$ $$\vec w'(y_0) = (0, 1, \partial_yf(x_0, y_0))$$
Their cross-product $(\partial_xf(x_0, y_0),\partial_yf(x_0, y_0),-1)$ is a normal vector to the tangent plane. The plane is parallel to the given line if and only if its normal vector is orthogonal to the direction vector of the line (i.e., any vector pointing along the line).

So I'll leave it to you to figure out a direction vector for the line, and to recall the condition for two vectors to be orthogonal.